# PHP: Trying to gt a part of url to INTO PHP

Tags: php

Okay so I have my PHP code: (I need help with the 4th line) More info down below the code.

Basicly I am trying to get code below. i am trying to put get  part of url but it doesn;'t work

```
$oIMDB = new IMDB('<?ph p echo$_GET("m");?> ')
```

and on the 4th line i put the code 
and the code doesn't work, how can i use it?

Comment: Try to read your own question. Do you understand what you was asking about?

Comment: you probably miss your code? :)

Comment: I believe we need both code and an example URL so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you mean this:

```
$oIMDB = new IMDB($_GET["m"]);
```

Comment: And I think *you* mean this: `$_GET["m"]` :)

Comment: And I hope he will check the GET data before using it :o

Comment: And *I* hope he will read a PHP tutorial before coding any more. :o)

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't need the php scripting block inside the class call.  Function parameters don't need quotes either unless you are using a literal string. Try

```
$oIMDB = new IMDB($_GET["m"])
```